# UTF-8 charset not applying

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

On a PHP project, in which header is imported trough PHP, special characters such as "ñ" or "á" do not appear.

Database is correctly encoded as UTF8-general-ci, and these characters display correctly inside the database. The issue is that when showing them on the site, all special characters look like this (it shoul be Germán Álvarez):

[image]

Is this because of importing head trough PHP (as seen abobe), instead of placing it directly on each PHP file? How can I solve this?

Header import code:

```
......

<html>

<?php
    include("../modules/head.php");
?>    

<body>  

......
```

Code inside file modules/head.php:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>Waisap | Sistema de mensajería interactivo </title>
    <meta name="description" content="-----" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="-----" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/basics/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
    <script src="../js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Does the text in `<title>` turn up correctly? Or is it just the result from the database?

Comment: Hi @MariM Yes, title shows correctly special characters

Comment: Solved with mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');